# "npm --save install <module>" without actually installing the module

Tags: node.js, npm

For my development setup, I'm using Node.js inside a Docker container. I'm placing the node_modules folder in the Docker image to avoid potential problems caused by architectural differences between the non-Linux host and the Docker engine. Whenever I add a module, I rebuild the image, a process that invokes `npm install` within the container. To add the dependency to package.json, I would run `npm --save install <module>` on the host computer since that's where I'm editing the files. That installs the module onto host computer which doesn't really need it. It's a waste of time and bandwidth.

I could manually edit package.json, but that's error-prone and requires looking up the module's version number. Is there a way to make the change through npm while avoiding the unneeded installation?

Answer (score 0):

when your docker container is running you can run npm install inside container:

```
docker exec -ti <container id or name> npm install --prefix ./path/to/your/app <package> --save
```